# "Click" event not getting triggered due to "blur"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

To reproduce the issue, use the fiddle at [1] and follow these steps:

1. Click on text box
2. Input some value in it
3. After value input, click of the "click me" button. Please Note, don't click anywhere else on the browser
4. You would see the "button click" event not getting triggered.

The HTML code looks like this,

```
   <div class="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="input"/>
    <div class="error">There is an error </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" id="button">Click Me</button>
    <div id="log">Logs</div>
```

The JavaScript code for the same is:

```
$(function () {
   $("input,button").on("click focus blur mousedown mouseup", function (e) {
     $("#log").append($("<div/>").html(e.target.id + " " + e.type))
     var self = this     
     if (self.id === "input" && e.type=="blur") {
       $(self).trigger("exit")
     }      
   })
   $(".wrapper").on("exit", function () {         
      $(this).find(".error").hide()
      $(this).find(".error").text("")
   })
})
```

The issue is reproducible in "Chrome" and "firefox". Is this a know bug in "Chrome" or anyone who have faced any similar issue ?

Ideally, the click event on button has to be triggered but somehow it doesn't ? I am not able to understand the cause or a possible fix.

I don't want to use the setTimeout() to defer the "blur" event execution

[1] https://jsfiddle.net/cg1j70vb/1/

Comment: This happens only the first time

Comment: Yes, it happens only for the first time. Also, commenting the following line ~$(this).find(".error").text("") ~ resolves the issue, but I need to understand the cause

Comment: Yes I did observe that.. possibly DOM re-paint when you remove the error text.

Comment: Is there anyway, I can keep the movement and still preserve the click event ? I would not want to increase the height of the button

Comment: You can use `visibility:hidden` property on the error text. That would not shift the button up

Comment: Yes, that would work but my use-case is also to change the HTML content of the error text dynamically ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132980/discussion-between-rishi-mehta-and-sandeep-nayak).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening since on `blur` of the `input` you are removing the `error` text. That shifts the `button` up (possibly DOM re-paint) and hence misses the `click`

I removed the error message and it works fine.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input,button").on("click focus blur mousedown mouseup", function(e) {
    $("#log").append($("<div/>").html(e.target.id + " " + e.type))
    if (this.id === "input" && e.type == "blur") {
      $(this).trigger("exit")
    }
  })
  $(".wrapper").on("exit", function() {
    $(this).find(".error").hide()
    $(this).find(".error").text("")
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" id="input" />

</div>
<button type="button" id="button">Click Me</button>
<div id="log">Logs</div>
```

Comment: I agree with you, the `hide()` function caused the button shifted at the same time as the click event

Comment: Yes, it is because of the movement of the button. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think its because the `hide()` function of your error message.

I tried to remove it and just replace the error message and it works.
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/dj27gau4/)